# OV 7670 + FIFO (AL422B) with arduino

Tags: arduino-uno

I just brought the camera OV7670 with fifo but I am unable to get the wiring of board with arduino and also I do not find any arduino library for OV7670 with fifo.

It will great if you can help to find some link which can help me.

Thanks,
Somnath

Comment: I google the OV7670 **with FIFO** and unfortunately I do not find the clear wiring with arduino and its simple code. I can find the book which can help as its written for this product only but it will be great if you can point to some good link which deal with OV7670 with FIFO. Please do not share the link for without fifo. Thanks.

Comment: Here is a link to a setup I built to explore the OV7670. There is a spread sheet with the wiring except for power. You are on your own for that, sorry.
https://joseph37920.github.io/OV7670-Explore/

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [link](http://www.element14.com/community/docs/DOC-76210/l/trying-to-use-a-camera-module-to-show-footage-to-a-lcd-tft-screen). Use google to find more. It is not difficult.

Comment: Hi Thanks for quick response . I already visited this page as its only page I found on web which work for camera + fifo https://github.com/arndtjenssen/ov7670.     All other explain camera without fifo ... I tried to check the code and code is basically written for avr and I know arduino is also based son avr only but it doesn't have DDRA and some other couple of register .